# using cisco vpn in batch mode, trouble with password

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

I'm trying to setup Cisco VPN connection in batch mode. I use

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client
vpncli.exe -s < uwvpn.txt
```

Where uwvpn.txt:

```
connect [vnp address]
[Group]
[user]
[password]
```

It seems everything is passed to the vpncli except the password.

I tested my commands by entering them manually in cmd and everything works fine, but there's a problem in batch mode.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Do you have a <cr> after password?

Answer (score 0):

I think the end of the password needs a linefeed, regardless LF or CR.  I have tried either one on my Windows and worked on either scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the configuration with your VPN client.

You have to figure out which lines are needed by testing different format.

In my case the client was passing Group and Username automatically because I had imported a Certification. So I just needed to confirm untrusted connection and provide the password.

```
connect <vpn.host.com>
y
<MyPassword>
```